# how do i copy non-match rows from one database to another database

Tags: sql-server

copying non-matched rows from one database to another database

I have tried this:

```
insert into pharmsql.[dbo].[SettingDetail] 
select * from PharmSQL_bkp.dbo.SettingDetail
```

Comment: @WEI_DBA Just enough karma to edit? Mine keeps going up on it's own. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the database where you you need to insert and pull from the source Database as follows.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable(field1, field2, field3)
   SELECT field1, field2, field3
     FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.SourceTable
     WHERE (some condition)
```